# How to enable drawing, highlighting and erasing function for pdf in new version of Microsoft Edge?

Tags: windows-10, pdf, microsoft-edge

I am reading a pdf and I'd like to highlight or mark specific sentences but I am not capable of doing that! What could I do to enable highlighting without downloading any chromian or edge extension?

[image]

Comment: It seems there is no way could achieve your goal without downloading any edge extension. For your reference:https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftedge/forum/msedge_%20read-msedge_win10/how-do-i-highlight-pdfs-in-the-new-microsoft-edge/c44608fc-e9b7-40b4-9622-2c343079ab1b#:~:text=Search%20for%20Enable%20Text%20Highlights,right%20click%20to%20select%20Highlights.

Answer (score 0):

Likely, Edge **cannot** do that, but free third-party tools such as [PDF-XChange Viewer](https://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer) have annotation capability.

First download the PDF file, then open in the viewer.